# Can't login to AskUbuntu, account shows as unregistered

Tags: support, login

When logged in, my profile shows "Unregistered". I can't vote or anything, I get the "Please login or register to vote for this post." message. When I log in (through Stack Exchange or google) everything looks alright, but I still get the "Please login or register to vote for this post.". Any way I try, I can't get it to work.

I have access to meta, however I can't post there ("Anonymous participation isn't allowed here; please log in before posting.").

Comment: I note you are logging in using your stackexchange account.  What happens if you instead login using your gmail account by clicking on the google login button?

Comment: I've switched to google account, still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you authorised access for askubuntu.com in your gmail account?

Comment: Yes, askubuntu.com has access to my gmail account.

Comment: not sure ... one of the other mods will look into this when they are online.

Comment: Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: You also have a Stack Exchange OpenID attached to your account. Have you tried signing in using that?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote earlier, I used both Gmail and Stack Exchange to log in, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contacted Askubuntu team directly and they've fixed my account.

Thanks for your help!